# Trouble with while loops and selection

Tags: python, loops, while-loop

```
selection=input("Which item do you use first? \n" +
    "a) Rescue flare \n" +
    "b) Pistol with 3 bullets \n" +
    "c) Machete knife \n")
while not selection != "a" or selection != "b" or selection != "c":
    print("You have an invalid option.  Please try again.")
    selection = input("Which item do you use first? \n" +
        "a) Rescue flare \n" +
        "b) Pistol with 3 bullets \n" +
        "c) Machete knife \n") 
if selection.lower()=="a":
    print("You see a ship passing by and shoot off the rescue flare. However, it seems like the ship did not see the flare.")
```

Hi,

So I decided to play around with loops for a beginner assignment.  However, what I noticed is now that I have included a loop (in this case while not), when I run it, even though I input valid options (a,b,c), it reads it as an invalid option.  Is it the way I set up my loop or indentation that is causing this issue?  Please let me know.  Appreciate any help I can get.

Answer (score 4):

`while not selection != "a"` includes a double negative and so translates to `while selection == "a"` you should simplify this line to:

`while selection not in {'a','b','c'}:`